# Error: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; near ''' at line 1"

Tags: javascript, mysql, jdbc, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm having a problem with my JavaScript code, it says the error is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''' at line 1

I'm trying to call this query: 'SELECT * FROM wp_fsqm_direct_52'

It connects to the database fine and show the database data in the sheet when I call the query like this: `var sql = 'SELECT * FROM wp_fsqm_direct_52';`

But when I call the exact same query from a cell in the A1 cell in the sheet `var sql = sheetData.getRange("A1").getValue();`, it returns me the error.

Sorry for my bad English, I'm from Venezuela, and this is my first time here.

This is my code:

```
function readFromTable() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheetDetails = ss.getSheetByName('Details');
  var sheetData = ss.getSheetByName('Query Sheet');
  var host = sheetDetails.getRange("B1").getValue();
  var databaseName = sheetDetails.getRange("B2").getValue();
  var userName = sheetDetails.getRange("B3").getValue();
  var password = sheetDetails.getRange("B4").getValue();
  var tableName = sheetDetails.getRange("B6").getValue();
  var url = 'jdbc:google:mysql://' + host + '/' + databaseName;
  Logger.log(url);
  Logger.log(userName);
  Logger.log(password);
  var sql = sheetData.getRange("A1").getValue();

  try {
    var connection = Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection(url, userName, password);
    var results = connection.createStatement().executeQuery(sql);
    var metaData = results.getMetaData();
    var columns = metaData.getColumnCount();

    // Retrieve metaData to a 2D array
    var values = [];
    var value = [];
    var element = '';
    // Get table headers
    for (i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
      element = metaData.getColumnLabel(i);
      value.push(element);
    }
    values.push(value);

    // Get table data row by row
    while (results.next()) {
      value = [];
      for (i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
        element = results.getString(i);
        value.push(element);
      }
      values.push(value);
    }

    // Cloese connection
    results.close();

    // Write data to sheet Data
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    sheetData.getRange(2, 1, values.length, value.length).setValues(values);
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast('Data has been updated.');
  } catch (err) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast(err.message);
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is that SQL in the code you posted?

Comment: Provide A1 screenshot and `Logger.log(sql)`

Comment: check what are you passing with lets say:
`alert sql`

Comment: Thanks, but after all, the mistake was that i used quotes in the A1 cell `'SELECT * FROM wp_fsqm_direct_52'`
i tried without them, and it worked `SELECT * FROM wp_fsqm_direct_52`
Thanks to @TheMaster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A1 should be plain text without quotes. You seem to have added extra quotes`'` in A1.

```
SELECT * FROM wp_fsqm_direct_52
```

Comment: Thanks you very much! i tried typing the query without quotes and it worked perfectly, it was just as simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

I find that running SQL on my website's database that it likes me put backticks around field names and single quotes around strings that I supply.  So here's an example that I just tried.

Unfortunately, the backticks are hard show so here because they invoke the code window so here is an image showing what I mean.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but at least in the google sheets, i can run an sql query without the backticks.
If i use them, the query works the same as if i dont